# Haskell: How to use this data structure

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I have to work with a code for an assignment that includes the following data structure:

```
data Rose a =  a :> [Rose a]
```

However, I have no idea how to work with this data structure, e.g.: how do I create an instance of it and how could I possibly loop through one?

If anyone could help me out on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor for this data type is `(:>)`, and it's type is `(:>) :: a -> [Rose a] -> Rose a`.  You can construct values with it like

```
> 1 :> [] :: Rose [Int]
1 :> []
> 1 :> [2 :> [], 3 :> [1 :> []]] :: Rose [Int]
1 :> [2 :> [], 3 :> [1 :> []]]
```

It is functionally equivalent to

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

with different names, i.e. `Tree <=> Rose` and `Node <=> :>`

If you wanted a `Functor` instance for it, you'd do

```
instance Functor (Rose a) where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
    fmap f (a :> rest) = (f a) :> (map (fmap f) rest)
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered my questions perfectly.

Comment: Or just `derive Functor` with the DeriveFunctor extension enabled :)

Comment: `(:>)` What is this datatype ? Can you point out some link for this ? (I'm seeing this for the first time.)

Comment: @Sibi (:>) is a data constructor with the type listed above.  The definition is given in the question.  It is a data constructor like any other in Haskell, except that it's an infix operator instead of a prefix function.  It isn't a type, it's the constructor for the type `Rose a`.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks. :) I thought that symbol was some predefined data constructor in haskell.